# Apply a decorator depending on the request method

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a Django view and a decorator `@token_required` but I would like to apply this decorator to a function **only if the method is `POST`**.
For now I have :

```
@token_required
def articles(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        ...
```

But the decorator is applied for GET and POST

Comment: The only way is to check request method in decorator. As the decorator is applied on function, so by definition it will be called ir-respective of the request method.

Comment: just send only post requests to articles view. why make things too complicated?

Comment: My first instinct would be to create your own decorator that only calls their decorator if the request type is POST. But that might be a little too meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap that decorator in your own decorator to do the check before applying it.  If it is a `POST` request, call the function obtained by calling `token_required` on the view function, otherwise just call the view function.

```
from functools import wraps

def token_required_on_post(f):
    require = token_required(f)

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return require(*args, **kwargs)

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@token_required_on_post
def articles(request):
    ...
```